# Servlet vs Filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

What is the difference between a **Servlet** and **Filter**? What do you recommend to use for authorization to pages?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use a `Filter` when you want to **filter and/or modify** requests based on specific conditions. Use a `Servlet` when you want to **control, preprocess and/or postprocess** requests.

The [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) mentions the following about filters:

> A filter is an object that can transform the header and content (or both) of a request or response. Filters differ from web components in that filters usually do not themselves create a response. Instead, a filter provides functionality that can be “attached” to any kind of web resource. Consequently, a filter should not have any dependencies on a web resource for which it is acting as a filter; this way it can be composed with more than one type of web resource.
>
> The main tasks that a filter can perform are as follows:
>
> - Query the request and act accordingly.
> - Block the request-and-response pair from passing any further.
> - Modify the request headers and data. You do this by providing a customized version of the request.
> - Modify the response headers and data. You do this by providing a customized version of the response.
> - Interact with external resources.

For authorization, a `Filter` is the best suited. Here's a basic kickoff example of how a filter checks requests for the logged-in user:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("user") == null) {
        // User is not logged in. Redirect to login page.
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("login");
    } else {
        // User is logged in. Just continue with request.
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Filters are best suited for authorization. This is because they can be configured to run for all pages of a site. So you only need one filter to protect all your pages.

Comment: All pages = pages which may required login.

Answer (score 2):

Using filter we can improve servlet performance--
    when request comes we can perform preprocessing on request, if request satisfies then we can forward to servlet otherwise give message to client provide appropriate information in request..