# Role of filter-mapping

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I'm trying out Spring and I've met the **filter-mapping** tag. What is its role when compared to the **servlet-mapping** tag? Is it executed in the background when the urls are called?

Comment: Are you talking about `<filter-mapping>` in `web.xml`? That's not part of Spring, but of Servlet API. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957165/servlet-vs-filter

Comment: Thanks. That link is very good.

Answer (score 2):

`<filter-mapping>` specifies when a [`javax.servlet.Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) is invoked.

Filters are invoked before the servlet they are defined for (you can map a filter to either an URL pattern or to a specific servlet)