# Can we use Filter instead of Servlet?

Tags: servlets, filter

Can we use Filter instead of Servlet? Can filter (without using servlet) be able to serve incoming request?

Answer (score 1):

Filters are used to modify the header and/or content of a request or response. I have never seen them used to create the response itself and I don't think they can be used for that, since they need to be "chained" with an actual resource. From the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html):

> A filter is an object that can transform the header and content (or
>   both) of a request or response. Filters differ from web components in
>   that filters usually do not themselves create a response. Instead, a
>   filter provides functionality that can be “attached” to any kind of
>   web resource.

Answer (score 1):

Filters have a wide array of uses; the Servlet 2.3 specification suggests the following uses:

- authentication filters
- logging and auditing filters
- image conversion filters
- data compression filters
- encryption filters
- tokenizing filters
- filters that trigger resource access events
- XSL/T filters that transform XML content
- MIME-type chain filters

[image: servlet filter]

Use a `Filter` when you want to **filter and/or modify requests** based on specific conditions.
Use a `Servlet` when you want to **control, preprocess and/or postprocess requests**.

Filter are best suited for authorization, because it can be configured to run for all pages of a site. So you only need one filter to protect all your pages.

Useful Links:

1. [filter tutorial](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/05/10/servlet_filters.html)
2. [filter in detail](http://www.servlets.com/soapbox/filters.html)
3. [referred answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957165/servlet-vs-filter)