# JSP page Reload

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my spring mvc application,I am facing a problem of page reloading on every request.Is there any way to restrict that.To be more specific,When I return the name of index.jsp page from controller it will obviously reload the page.How Can I restrict that thing in the index.jsp page.Suppose some part of the page is required to interact with Database and it should be shown on the same index.jsp page as well.How I can achieve this requirement without reloading the index.jsp page completely.Could you please provide me some example for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/Filter.html) for that. I am not providing any code here, just try to explain the concept.

Filters have a wide array of uses; the Servlet 2.3 specification suggests the following uses:

- authentication filters
- logging and auditing filters
- image conversion filters
- data compression filters
- encryption filters
- tokenizing filters
- filters that trigger resource access events
- XSL/T filters that transform XML content
- MIME-type chain filters

[image: servlet filter]

Use a `Filter` when you want to **filter and/or modify requests** based on specific conditions.
Use a `Servlet` when you want to **control, preprocess and/or postprocess requests**.

Filter are best suited for authorization, because it can be configured to run for all pages of a site. So you only need one filter to protect all your pages.

### Useful Links:

1. [filter tutorial](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/05/10/servlet_filters.html)
2. [filter in detail](http://www.servlets.com/soapbox/filters.html)
3. [referred answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957165/servlet-vs-filter)
4. [Oracle tutorial on Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)

Answer (score 0):

sorry if i missunderstanding you!

i don't know what do you want to do but i can imagine the following solution.

first direct call to jsp should check a session value, if not exists, redirect from jsp to servlet, in the servlet do what you wand and finally put this session value, and redirect back to jsp.

a good concept depends on what you want to do exactly. You can manage this issue using a PhaseListener or a Filter. but if you just want to manage this one redirect, then no need of Filter or PhaseListener